# Como esconder a seta de voltar no xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

Na minha aplicação mobile não gostaria que existisse na página home a opção de voltar, pois se fizer isso a pessoa volta para a tela de login. Como faço para remover essa seta apenas dessa página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No XAML você pode ocultar o botão através da AttachedProperty `HasBackButton` da `NavigationPage` assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SeuNamespace.Views"
             x:Class="SeuNamespace.Views.SuaPage"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
    <!-- Conteúdo da sua página -->
</ContentPage>
```

No codebehind seria assim:

```
namespace SeuNamespace.Views 
{
    public partial class SuaPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SuaPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Lembre-se de que sempre haverá a possibilidade de o usuario usar o botão voltar do hardware. Nesse caso, você pode tratar sobrescrevendo o manipulador do evento correspondente através do método `OnBackButtonPressed` da página retornando `true`. Assim:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    // Alguma lógica de tratamento
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Realmente eu fiz de forma semelhante ontem e funcionou... De qualquer forma muito obrigado!!!